# Image Sizes in iOS

Tags: ios, image, assets

I have a question about assets. When I have an image that has to be half of the screen, how many image files do I need? 
For the iPhone 5 I need @1x, @2x and @3x; for the iPhone 6 I need @1x, @2x and @3x; for the iPhone 7...

This is the right way? If that the case, I will have to get the size of the device through code and then, depending of the size, use the right image?

If this is not the right way and I have to make a unique image in PDF from with single scalable image, what should be the size  in pixels (width and height) for that image.

This is something I am struggling with, because it is different from using fixed images where all I need is @1x, @2x and @3x for all the devices

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: The iPhone 5 only needs `@2x`. The iPhone 6 only needs `@2x`. The iPhone 6+ only needs `@3x`, etc.

Comment: Well yes, but if I need @2x for the different devices (different heights), do I have to get the size of the device through code and then put the right image? Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: @DanielFernandezY no you dont, it will automatically get the correct image to put, the only thing you need is the name without suffix

Answer (score 1):

That's one nice feature about xcassets is they handle that stuff for you. You don't need to programatically get the device type and specify the image that device will need.

As an example, if you're using a storyboard, simply assign a UIImageView's image property to an image contained in your xcassets folder and boom - at run time the correct image size will be used based on the device running it. This is assuming that in XCAssets you've given it a @1x, @2x, and @3x image sizes.

Make sure to drag and drop images into all 3 boxes from finder:

[image]

Comment: That works for fixed sized images like for icons. It doesn't work for device screen sized images. The iPhone 5 and 6 are both `@2x` but they have different sized screens.

Comment: I see, in this case it would depend on what you're wanting to display. If it's a solid color, just use autolayout constraints to ensure the image takes up half the screen like you're wanting. If you have two specific images built exactly for iPhone 5 and 6 then yes you'll have to detect the device type.

Comment: So I have to detect the device type and then select the image I want to use. This mean I will need to have @ 2x for iPhone 5, @ 2x for iPhone 6 / 6s, @ 3x for iPhone 6+ / 6s+ ... Is this the best way to go? or can I use something similar with PDF Images?